# Django: usage of prefetch_related

Tags: python, django

I have some models with this relation:

```
EmailReport --many-to-many--> PaymentReport --foreign-key--> Shop --many-to-many--> users
```

Now I want to reach the users from EmailReport.
I tried this query but failed:

```py
query = models.EmailReport.objects.prefetch_related('payment_report').prefetch_related('shop__users').filter(pk__in=ids)
```

Anyone knows the correct query?

#### Update:

Thanks to @bartosz-stasiak
The query is:

```
objects= EmailReport.objects.prefetch_related('payment_report__shop__users').filter(pk__in=ids)
```

But how can I access to the prepetch users?
Tried this and failed:

```
objects= EmailReport.objects.prefetch_related('payment_report__shop__users').filter(pk__in=ids)
for object in objects:
   object.users.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably:

```
email_reports = EmailReport.objects.prefetch_related('payment_report__shop__users').filter(pk__in=ids)
```

(That are `ids` here? Users ids or EmailReport ids?)

This shoud be minimal amount of queries. Just remember that you can't do further filtering or it will break the prefetch.

Then there are few ways to get the users. The most simple will probably be: (but can be unefficient)

```
users_from_query = []
for email_report in email_reports:
    for pr in email_report.payment_report.all()
        users_from_query.extend(pr.shop.users.all())
```

Comment: EmailReport ids

Comment: And how can I retrieve the users?

Comment: What if I want to get phone number of users into the list sir?

Comment: Replace `pr.shop.users.all()` with `pr.shop.users.all().values_list("phone_number", flat=True)` assuing that field name is `phone_number` and you want just the phone numbers